# How will we handle various mail related tags?

Tags: discussion

We just launched and we already have three:

- mail
- email
- civimail

Civi is wide enough that these need not be duplicates, as it also handles snail mail and non-civimail mailing. This however is not so obvious, user friendly, when you're choosing tags. Do we start consolidating, just expand the tag wikis or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mail and email are obviously synonyms.  However, there may be a useful distinction between CiviMail and base-level email configuration.  Someone having outbound email trouble leading to no receipts going out isn't necessarily going to be looking to a CiviMail tag, especially if they think "I don't use CiviMail; I use MailChimp".

Comment: What do you suggest for snail mail then?

Comment: There's no mail tool--just labels or pdf letters, which are their own things.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have 1250 reputation, you can define [tag synonyms](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).